# Proof of power mean inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How do we prove this:

$$\left(\frac{\sum_{r=1}^na_r}n\right)^2 < \frac{\sum_{r=1}^n {a_r}^2}n $$ 
Thanks!

Edit: forgot to mention that $a_1+..+a_n=1$

Edit 2: Ok done..that was an insane hint thanks but how did you know that this had to be done, I mean it's not obvious at all?? What's the intuition that I had to have?

Comment: Can you use [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality)? ;-)

Comment: I think you need to put more hypothesis than this, is $0\le a_r\le 1$ or just positive or $a_r\le 0$ ?, also have you tried anything?

Comment: haha no, I wish.. it's a small part of a larger problem I'm trying to solve. I've been stuck for a few hours

Comment: Ana you're absolutely right I forgot to add an extremely important part I'll edit the post now!

Comment: Hint: $0\le \sum (a_r -A)^2$, where $n*A=\sum a_r$.

Comment: Yes i've tried the geo-arith mean inequality

Comment: Thanks for the hint I'll look into it now!

Comment: The strict inequaltity is false, you have to use $\le$ otherwise you get the contradiction $1/n^2 < 1/n^2$ for $a_r=1/n$.

Comment: You just have to prove $\displaystyle{\large%
\sum_{r = 1}^{n}a_{r}^{2}\ >\ {1 \over n}}$ given $\displaystyle{\large\sum_{r = 1}^{n}a_{r}\ =\ 1}$. See @AnaGalois comment.

Comment: $a_1+..+a_n=1$ will not make any difference. You can divide both sides by $(a_1+..+a_n)^2$ to get this property.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{%
\mbox{Write}\
a_{r} \equiv {1 \over n} + \epsilon_{r}
}\,$. Then

$$
\sum_{r = 1}^{n}a_{r}^{2}
=
{1 \over n}
+
{2 \over n}\ \overbrace{\sum_{r = 1}^{n}\epsilon_{r}}^{\large =\ 0}
+
\sum_{r = 1}^{n}\epsilon_{r}^{2}\
\geq\
{1 \over n}
$$

Comment: Again: This is wrong if all $a_r=1/n$ or $\epsilon_r=0$. You can only show $\ge$ or must exclude this case.

Comment: @gammatester $\qquad$ Thanks.